# How to add lang attribute to html tag in Next.js?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

After running some performance check on my Next.js portfolio site I noticed that the main `index.html` is missing a `lang` attribute - which gets returned as a deduction from the accessibility score.

I can add the locale by using the i18n setup to `next.config.js`, but those features are incompatible with `next export` - the site is statically generated.

```sh
Error: i18n support is not compatible with next export. See here for more info on deploying: https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment
```

Are there any other ways to add the `lang` attribute?

Comment: Isn't this just a case of adding the `lang` attribute to your `<Html>` tag in your [custom `_document`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)?

Comment: @juliomalves I will add it there, but I was thinking the NextJS team would have included the lang value by default. I guess that they didn't because they can't know the default for every project. Most official docs suggest to use the `internationalisation` features for this, but as per my post that features isn't supported by `next export`. Want to add this as an answer? Seems to be closest to a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the `lang` attribute to the `<Html>` tag in your [custom `_document`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Comment: like in step 11 here in this tutorial: https://dev.to/adrai/static-html-export-with-i18n-compatibility-in-nextjs-8cd#recipe

Comment: This doesn't set the language dynamically - it's just hard coded to 'en'

Comment: @icc97 That's correct, it wasn't a requirement of the original question.

Comment: Ah indeed, you're correct :)

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to @juliomalves answer, next.config.js file can also be used to define lang.

create a file called "next.config.js" in the root of your project with the below,

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ["en"],
        defaultLocale: "en",
    },
};
```

ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction

Comment: Note that this approach will enable Next.js [i18n routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing), which may not always be desired.

Comment: To add to @juliomalves 's comment

{{Note that this approach will enable Next.js i18n routing, which may not always be desired.}}

An example of this is static file exports using `next export` - Internationalisation requires a server to function https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export